# mysql - 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' when INSERT multiple values from two different tables into a 'bridge table'

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables:

1. users
2. roles
3. users_roles (the 'bridge table')

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`users_roles` (`user_id`, `role_id`)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM `db`.`users` WHERE username like '%@gmail.com'), (Select id from roles where authority="can_view"));
```

Since there are hundreds of `user_id` with the username like %gmail.com, I'm getting the error "**Subquery returns more than 1 row**". Also, there's only one authority, that's why i used the = operator. I'm aware I should use the `IN` operator when working with multiple values, but I don't seem to know how to properly write this query with the first `SELECT`.

How can i solve this problem? Help!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do two separate queries, one for user_id and one for role_id.  Since they're not joined they could have a different number of results. And what happens if you return 30 user_id's but only get 15 role_id? It doesn't know how to match that up. You need to join your tables to give a single result set for your insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO db.users_roles (user_id, role_id) 
    SELECT u.id, r.id
    FROM db.users u JOIN
         roles r
         ON u.username like '%@gmail.com' AND
            r.authority = 'can_view';
```

Comment: Hi!! I executed this query and I'm getting this error 'Column count doesnt match value count at row 1'

Comment: INSERT INTO db.users_roles (user_id, role_id) 
    SELECT u.id,r.id
    FROM db.users u JOIN
         roles r
         ON u.username like '%@gmail.com' AND
            r.authority = 'can_view';

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to give `can_view` permission to existing users with a gmail account. If that is the case, there is no need for you to select from the `roles` table. Just run the `roles` table query to get the `can_view` permission ID and then you can just hard code that into the query like so:

`INSERT INTO db.users_roles (user_id, role_id) SELECT id, RoleIDFromPreviousQueryHere FROM db.users WHERE username like '%@gmail.com'`